# Failed to update to new Evernote 3.5.5 on Windows-7-x64

Tags: windows-7-x64, auto-update, evernote

Can't install or update Evernote 3.5.5 on windows-7-x64.
Currently have Evernote 3.5.4 running and after auto-update it's still 3.5.4...
I've also tried uninstalling 3.5.4 and installing 3.5.5 and finally I ended up restoring yesterdays backup because Evernote didn't install at all. (Installer ran fine but no files on the disk after the installation.)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by completely removing the old version (including registry entries) and reinstall the new version on the "clean" system.

Used [RevoUnistaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) for the easy and clean uninstall